# Validate legitimacy of email address before sending email?

Tags: smtp

We're sending out emails to people when they sign up for our service, but a lot of them are bouncing (partially our fault for using a bogus email in some end-to-end tests), and AWS has informed us that additional bouncing could be bad for our instances' health.

So, I'm trying to come up with a means of validation (or at least a way to stop us from sending to bad addresses).

It looks like there's [a means of asking SMTP servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_verification) if they know of an address, but there's some controversy around the technique (it isn't guaranteed to work, and doing too much of it makes you look like a spammer; could get you blacklisted in the worst case).

I guess the other option here is to keep track of what we've seen bounce and just dump 'bad' emails into a database collection, although there are problems with this too (if someone signs up for that email address later, they're unable to sign up for the service; we still send at least one bounced email even in the best case).

My question is: is there a better option, one that I'm missing? This seems like the sort of issue that should be A Solved Problem™, but I'm not finding any applicable patterns.

Answer (score -1):

This is a solved problem. Step 1 is just to validate the syntax of the email address (using something like [EmailValidation](https://github.com/jstedfast/EmailValidation)) and then step 2 is to send an email to the address with a link for the user to click to verify their email address. Until the user clicks the link in their email, don't add the address to your database.